# Error when using shutdown command in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
read -p 'Want to use the timer (y/n) ? ' jwb2
    if [[ $jwb2 =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        echo -n "Now Days "
        date +"%A and hour %T"
        read -p 'How many hours [24hrs] :' jwb3
        echo Process the command
        sudo bash -c "Shutdown -h $jwb3"
    fi
```

and running the script now,

```
me@linux:$./main.sh
Want to use the timer (y/n) ? y
Now Days Thursday and hour 16:09:49
How many hours [24hrs] :18:00
Process the command
```

> bash: Shutdown: command not found

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Use the full path for the `shutdown` command as `/sbin/shutdown -h $jwb3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shutdown` instead `Shutdown`.

Comment: Remains the same

Comment: Show `whereis -b shutdown`